# Find f with A plane curve whose equation is $y - f (x) = 0$ passes through the origin.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, optimization, rectangles

A plane curve whose equation is $y - f (x) = 0$ passes through the origin.Consider the rectangle $R_x$ formed by the coordinate axes and lines parallel to the axis passing through the point $(x, f (x))$ of the curve lines. If the curve divides the rectangle into two regions and one of the area of the region is 10 times the area of the other.

How can I find $f$.I stuck in this exercise some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of rectangle : $x\times f(x)$

One part of area: $\int_0^x f(x) dx$.

Can you do it now?

Comment: but how can i interpret "If the curve divides the rectangle into two regions and one of the area of the region is 10 times the area of the other".

Comment: A curve passes though two opposite vertices of a rectangle and thus dividing it into two parts

Comment: mmmmm ok i will try again ....

Comment: i got the equation $11 (\int_0^x f(x) dx - xf(x)) = 0$ how can i solve this ??

Comment: Differentiate both sides. and you will get a differential equation.

Comment: then i need to solve the differential equation 11(f(x) - f(x) + f´(x)x) = 0 but this is 11(y´x) = 0 ?? its that correct?